# How to safely proxy an image from any url and avoid exploits?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I'd like to proxy images from any other site on my site, for example:

http://example.com/image?url=XXX

where `XXX` is an url to any image at all on the net, most probably an image from twitter, facebook or another social network.

#### How can I do this safely, and

- avoid being an [open redirect](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet) (ie stop hackers from trying to use urls like so `http://example.com/images?url=http://SomeHackerWebsite.com/steal_cookies_or_redirect`
- force the browser to treat the response as an image, no matter what

I'm using Java/Jersey/JaxRS, and was thinking of just setting the response media type to `image/*` but wasn't sure if this would be enough, as I can't really blacklist any urls, as I can't determine an optimal whitelist for twitter/facebook/etc.

#### Currently I'm already doing the following:

- using secure, http only cookies so 3rd party javascript can't steal my sites cookies
- only allowing authenticated requests
- signing requests, so users can't easily fiddle with each others requests, though this doesn't stop the original request from being a request to non image content.

Comment: how about returning base64 string?

Comment: hmmm.... good point... It'll depend on the browsers we support, but this is something to consider... you should add this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very huge and hard question. I think must use multiple approach for safety. for example return base64 instead of image. There’s also some drawbacks:

- base64 encoding makes file sizes roughly 33% larger than their original binary representations, which means more data down the wire (this might be exceptionally painful on mobile networks)
- data URIs aren’t supported on IE6 or IE7
- base64 encoded data may possibly take longer to process than binary data (anyone want to do a study on this?) (again, this might be exceptionally painful for mobile devices, which have more limited CPU and memory) (side note: CSS background-images seem to actually be faster than img tags)

another way is we have tagging system! in this system image that access many time detected and those consider by human.

Third way is consider source of requests. If you have suspicious site you can consider image that those site reference it.

Comment: Great points all around - the third way may be a possibility and would 100% work... I think I can get the original source of the requests, so I can tell from that if they're legit or not... thanks for the great ideas!